# Pyqt4 to Pyqt5 and python code error

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, python-3.5, python-3.4, pyqt5

i switch from Pyqt4 to Pyqt5 and from python2.7 to 3.4 and i found a bug in Pyqt5 so i upgrade it to the last version which is not suppoted by python3.4 . than i used python3.5 and it work fine except one module called pymaxwell.
always the app crash and closed and to confirm i go back to python2.7 and i use pyqt5 for python2.7 and the same error ; the app closed immediately and show me an error in a part in the code which is work well with pyqt4.
in the gif a comparaison between Pyqt4/Pyqt5 with python2.7

comparison

[image]

the part of the code which have problem:

```
        self.btnMXSmxm()
        self.mxs_filt.setChecked(True)
        self.show_folder.setChecked(False)
        inPath = self.input_mxs_scene_2.text();
        self.input_mxs_scene.setText(inPath);
        self.mxm_list.clear()
        if len(inPath) == 0:
           self.chosen_material.clear()
        # loop over all mxs
        else:
            mxsList = self.input_mxs_scene.text()
            print mxsList
            if not len(mxsList) == 0:
                scene = Cmaxwell(mwcallback);
                ok = scene.readMXS(mxsList);
                sceneMaterials = scene.getMaterialNames();
                materialcount = int(scene.getMaterialsCount()[0])
                if os.path.isfile(self.input_mxs_scene.text()):
                    for name in sceneMaterials:
                        scenematerial = scene.getMaterial(name)
```

Comment: In the image samples that you use `mxsList = self.input_mxs_scene.text().toAscci().data()` instead in the code you place only samples `mxsList = self.input_mxs_scene.text()`, which code are you using?

Comment: both of them give the same result and the same error

Comment: Show only one version since you confuse us, in addition your error is irreproducible since you show an incomplete code, if you want us to help you could publish your project in github or similar and share the link.

Comment: i just want if pyqt5 have a problem with the code; because it work fine with pyqt4; so maybe this is a bug in pyqt5 and the code need pymaxwell and maxwell render installed in the system ; who want download them to try ?

Comment: mmmm, because to blame a bug, Qt5 made many changes, and therefore pyqt5, in addition to that pyqt5 tries to use things native to python, for example in PyQt4 the functions that worked with text used the class QString, this tenie the method toAscci as samples in your code, but in PyQt5 uses the native str data type of python, I recommend you run it from the terminal and observe the error messages, look in the docs if the function has renamed or deleted the functions.

Comment: thanks i also asked pymaxwell developers to know about the problem; and every pyqt5 version give me a different error ; i tried many python version with many pyqt5 versions , what i like in pyqt5 is easier to use in some things and have bettr media player ; i will create simple code and try with it; thanks for informations

Comment: in this line : inPath = self.input_mxs_scene_2.text(); i remove the comma (;) and than the error disappear but now i have other problem with pymaxwell and i wait response of the deveolpers

Comment: problem solved ; python with pyqt5 don't read mxsList so i use str(mxsList) and it work fine

Comment: and big thanks eyllanesc ; you give an idea how to resolve the problem

Comment: with python 2.7 and pyqt5 work fine but the problem still happen with python 3.5 and pyqt5 even i use str()

Answer (score 0):

problem solved;
i use python 3.5.4 and pyqt 5.9
now even i use read(file) or read(str(file)) don't give any error.
and i find that with pyqt5 it need new arrangement of some lines in the code.
i modify the code and it work :

```
        mxsList = self.input_mxs_scene.text()
        scene = Cmaxwell(mwcallback)
        materialcount = int(scene.getMaterialsCount()[0])
        if not len(inPath) == 0:
            if os.path.isfile(self.input_mxs_scene.text()):
                ok = scene.readMXS(mxsList)
                sceneMaterials = scene.getMaterialNames()
                if not len(mxsList) == 0:
                    for name in sceneMaterials:
                        scenematerial = scene.getMaterial(name)
                        # #print scenematerial
                        self.mxm_list.addItem(name)
```

i also add : from PyQt5.QtCore import *
that solve other problem with reading media files

after many tries with different versions of python and pyqt5 ; the best versions works well together , **python 2.7.9** and pyqt5 from github : 
[PyQt 5.7.1 for Python 2.7](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5)